# Swift - the text field returns 0 even though I inserted a different number

Tags: ios, swift, text, random

I'm new to Swift, and I'm trying to make a little app that, given two values (a,b) returns a random number between the two numbers (a < randomnumber < b)

The user has to write the values of a and b in two different text fields and then just press a button and that's it

The problem is:
I told the NSLog to display the two values just before generating the random number because I noticed something wasn't working as it was supposed to, and the result is that apparently the second value I insert, whether it is a or b, for some (unknown) reason, equals 0 ! For example, if I write in the a-textfield the value 10 and then I insert the value 40 in the b-textfield, the NSLog displays a = 10, b = 0. If I insert the b value before, the NSLog displays b = 40, a = 0.
These are the lines of code :

```
@IBAction func TextAAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    a = UInt32(TextA.text!)!

}


@IBAction func TextBAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    b = UInt32(TextB.text!)!

}


@IBAction func randomInBetweenAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("a=%ld, b=%ld", a, b)
    randomInBetween()
    unHide()
    Label.text = "\(randomNumberInBetween)"

}
```

as you can see the value a is equal to the value that is inserted in the TextA field and the value b is equal to the value that is inserted in the TextB field

the randomInBetween() is the function that generates a random number between a and b, and it does work.. the problem is that one of the values (the second one I insert) is always 0 for some reason, even if I set it to a different number!

Any ideas on why this happens and how to work it out?

@ReinerMelian this is the full code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var InvariableLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TextA: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var TextB: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AndLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Hide()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var randomNumber = Int()


func randomNUMBER() -> Int {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random())
    return randomNumber
}

func Hide() {
    Label.hidden = true
}

func unHide() {
    Label.hidden = false
}

var a = UInt32()
var b = UInt32()

var randomNumberInBetween = Int()

func randomInBetween() -> Int {
    if b>a {
        randomNumberInBetween = Int(arc4random_uniform(b - a) + a)
         return randomNumberInBetween

    }  else {
randomNumberInBetween = Int(arc4random_uniform(a - b) + a)
return randomNumberInBetween
}


}



@IBAction func ButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    randomNUMBER()
    unHide()
    Label.text = "\(randomNumber)"
    NSLog("\(randomNumber)")
}


@IBAction func TextAAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    a = UInt32(TextA.text!)!


}


@IBAction func TextBAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    b = UInt32(TextB.text!)!

}


@IBAction func randomInBetweenAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("a=%ld, b=%ld", a, b)
    randomInBetween()
    NSLog("\(randomInBetween)")
    unHide()
    Label.text = "\(randomNumberInBetween)"
    NSLog("\(randomInBetween)")
}



}
```

(PS: as you can see, there is also a function that generates a random number without any sort of constraints, but that part works just fine.. the problem is with the other part of the code, the one that returns a random number between two given values (a,b) )

Comment: Your `a` and `b` variables are UInt32 also?

Comment: this code     `@IBAction func excuteCode(sender: AnyObject) {
        let a : Int32 = Int32(textA.text!)!
        let b : Int32 = Int32(textB.text!)!
        
        NSLog("a=%ld, b=%ld", a, b)
    }`works for me without problems

Comment: @ReinierMelian both a and b are UInt32, yes. I don't know what the problem is in my code, but either a or b equals 0 always.. it's driving me crazy!

Comment: can you post your other code? to see what is happening? because the code that I posted on my last comment works just fine

Comment: what is the actual action that triggers `TextAAction` and `TextBAction`? a button tap?

Comment: @ReinierMelian done! check it out:)

Comment: @AndréSlotta mm those are two text fields.. you insert values in TextA and TextB and then press a button that is supposed to generate a random number between those values and display it on a label (was it what you meant?)

Comment: @tommsyeah well... `@IBAction func randomInBetweenAction(sender: AnyObject)` is the button tap. but what is `@IBAction func TextAAction(sender: AnyObject)` and `@IBAction func TextBAction(sender: AnyObject)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure, your outlets (`TextA`, `TextB`) and your IBAction (`randomInBetweenAction`) are wired up correctly, remove

```
@IBAction func TextAAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    a = UInt32(TextA.text!)!

}
```

and

```
@IBAction func TextBAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    b = UInt32(TextB.text!)!

}
```

and try this function on button tap:

```
@IBAction func randomInBetweenAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    a = UInt32(TextA.text!)!
    b = UInt32(TextB.text!)!
    NSLog("a=%ld, b=%ld", a, b)
    randomInBetween()
    NSLog("\(randomInBetween)")
    unHide()
    Label.text = "\(randomNumberInBetween)"
    NSLog("\(randomInBetween)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT, it worked!! I don't know why but for some reason I really thought I had to have an action for each text field in order tell each one of them what to do when the user inserts a value.. But it just wasn't necessary! Thank you:)

Comment: well. you could add an action to assign the `text` of the textfields to your variables `a` / `b` as soon as the user changes the text... but in your case it is enough to do that when the user presses the button to generate the random number. glad i could help :)